# (Java/MySQl) Generate daynamic buttons

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I just try to genereate Buttons via MySql. 
I got an MySql DB where I store the Button relevant Data (Name etc)
Now I tried to generate for each entry a own Button. The Debug does print in the Console but the Buttons doesnt shown up. Any Ideas or tips. Would like to get a advice. I got one class swing and one where I handle all mysql requests.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class swing {
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainMenu");
    static  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.add(panel);
        JButton button = new JButton("Dursuchen");
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new search());

    }



    public  static  void addButton(String name){
        JPanel rowPanel = new JPanel();
        System.out.println("addButton " + name);
        JButton button = new JButton(name);
        rowPanel.add(button);
        //button.addActionListener(new search());
    }

    static  class Action implements  ActionListener{
        public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Clicked");
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setSize(200,200);
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame2.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);
        }
    }
    static  class search implements  ActionListener{
        public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Search.getAllFromKat(0);

        }
    }

}
```

MySql Part where I call the addButton();
This part is in another class Called mysqlaccess.java

```
 public static void showAllFromKat(int ID){
        con = getInstance();
        if(con != null){
            Statement query;
            try{
                query = con.createStatement();
                String sql =
                        "SELECT * FROM learn_themen_db";
                ResultSet result = query.executeQuery(sql);
                while(result.next()){
                    int KatID = result.getInt("Kat_ID");
                    String DisplayName = result.getString("Display_Name");
                    if(KatID == ID){
                        System.out.println(DisplayName);
                        swing.addButton(DisplayName);
                    }

                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Repaint()` after adding the buttons?

Comment: Where is rowPanel being added to the JFrame?

Comment: rowPanel isnt added I removed it. It was just a test. How does the Repaint() work?

Comment: Your code above is adding the buttons to rowPanel in rowPanel.add(button);
The buttons need to be added to a visible panel in order to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes to your code and it will display your buttons.

```
public static void addButton(String name)
{
    System.out.println("addButton " + name);

    JButton button = new JButton(name);

    panel.add(button);
    panel.revalidate();
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks this was my problem :) I´m new add Java GUI and didnt found any guide that explained it good enough ^^